# Does the Content Resolver query retrieves all the data at once?

Tags: android, sqlite, query-optimization, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

Does the Content Resolver query retrieves all the data at once? if so, how to optimize this to retrieve the data as the cursor moves? (is it possible at all? if not, how to optimize this process?)

Answer (score 1):

Content resolvers are designed to allow accessing data in other apps, so to reduce communication overhead, they try to retrieve as much data as possible (using a [CursorWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorWindow)).

However, calling `query()` and then iterating over the cursor with `moveToNext()` is the *only* way to retrieve data, so there is nothing you can do to optimize it.

When you are not reading but modifying data, and have multiple rows, you should use functions such as [bulkInsert()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#bulkInsert(android.net.Uri,%20android.content.ContentValues[])) or [applyBatch()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#applyBatch(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.content.ContentProviderOperation%3E)).

Comment: `Being the only way to retrieve data` does not mean `there is nothing you can do to optimize it.` Right?

Comment: What are you going to do? There is no call to retrieve multiple rows at once.

Answer (score 0):

To few information, write more precicely what do you want to get in your app? `ContentResolver` only handle a query that you declare in `ContentProvider`. What data query command will return, depends on you.

Comment: This is not an answer either. better ask such questions in the comment